# what are the best toolkits and technologies that are available for building a scalable datastore?

Tags: erlang, scalability, bigdata, datastore

I’m planning on developing a distributed datastore which is able to cope with the scalability, flexibility and fault tolerance.

I've looked at Erlang but discovered a few negative opinions.

Could I use AKKA for building a datastore?

Comment: Negative opinions? Looks like you asked the wrong people!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [Riak](http://basho.com/riak/) and its [`riak_core`](https://github.com/basho/riak_core). It's one interesting way to go.

Comment: Genomu is, IIRC, built with `riak_core` under the hood, and obviously Riak is as well.